# cannot access mariadb remotely

Tags: remote-access, mariadb

I'm a new user for Linux and I was given a remote server to play with. I'm trying to access the mariadb database remotely in this server. I got 'connection refused' error when I tried it.

```
pramod@debian:~$ mysql -h master -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'master' (111 "Connection refused")
```

So did some research in the internet and tried the following to find the problem. I ran a ps and got the following results:

```
[pramod@master my.cnf.d]$ ps auxf | grep mysql
pramod 17612  0.0  0.0 112652   980 pts/2    S+   10:49   0:00              \_ grep --color=auto mysql
mysql    13551  0.0  0.0 917228 97276 ?        Sl   09:55   0:00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/home/database/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking --log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log --pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid --socket=/home/database/mysql/mysql.sock
```

So I figured that --skip-networking is in the arguments (last line) and I think that should be the problem. So I checked my my.cnf file. It doesn't have it. I did a search on the /etc/ folder as follows:

```
[root@master my.cnf.d]# grep -rnw '/etc/' -e 'skip-networking'
```

with no luck. Then I searched for skip_networking instead. Which turned out the following:

```
[root@master my.cnf.d]# grep -rnw '/etc/' -e 'skip_networking'
/etc/akonadi/mysql-global-big.conf:88:skip_networking
/etc/akonadi/mysql-global.conf:88:skip_networking
/etc/akonadi/mysql-global-mobile.conf:88:skip_networking
```

Now I don't know if I should mess with those files. Probably I shouldn't.

**Is there anything else I could try?**

**Any guesses where the problem might lie? Is my search for 'skip-networking' line correct?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the user permissions to access the DB remotely first, you do this from the mysql prompt:

In the case of the user: root to be allowed to access from the network range: 192.168.100.x/24:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.100.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-new-password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

In case you want to allow the user to connect from any network you can just substitute "192.168.100.%" with the wildcard: %

Also, this command states a new password for the user.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: My bad, I didn't fully read one of the commands you pasted. You do need to disable the  skip_networking. More info: [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_networking)

It's a boolean, set it as OFF